# React Native pass state reference instead of state value

Tags: react-native, reference, state

I'm trying to build a string consisting of several  components. On a button click the text should change. The problem I ran into is that the string contains state variables. When the string is created the current value of the state is printed but it does not keep the reference. So if the state changes the string does not.

I have tried to set secondText to {this.state.age} but this gives me a syntax error...

**The code**

```
import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

    class App extends React.Component{

      constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
          
          age: 20,
          height: 190,
          firstText: 'I am',
          secondText: null
        }
      }


      changeText(props){

        switch(props) {

          case 'height':
            this.setState({
              secondText: this.state.height
            });
            break;

          default:
            this.setState({
              secondText: this.state.age
            });   
        }
      }

      change = ()=>{
        this.setState({
          age: 22,
        })
      }

      render(){

        return(
          <View>
            <View>
              <Text>
                <Text>{this.state.firstText}</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.secondText}</Text>
              </Text>

              <Text>{this.state.result}</Text>
            </View>

            <View>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.changeText.bind(this,'height')}>
                <View>
                  <Text>Height?</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>

              <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.changeText.bind(this,'age')}>
                <View>
                  <Text>Age?</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>

              <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.change.bind(this, 22)}>
                <View>
                  <Text> change Age</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>


            </View>
          </View>

        )
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: Your problem is the value was changing but it is not refreshing. because you are not using usestate

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My code was too simplified. All of the functions are inside a class component. I'll update it.

Comment: instead write a simple snippet which reproduce your problem. So that one can just copy your snippet and solve your problem.

Comment: I have updated the snipped :)